# <esi:include> with network-path reference

Tags: html, url, https, esi, edge-side-includes

I just discovered that performing an `<esi:include src="url" />` using a [network-path reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) is not possible; it returns an error in the inclusion.

Is possible to include an absolute URL omitting the protocol/scheme?

I need to include pages via **http** or **https** depending on the protocol/scheme of the calling page

(so include *http://example.com/included* if I'm including in *http://example.com/container*,
or include *https://example.com/included* if I'm including in *https://example.com/container*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found that my problem was not with *ESI Include*.

The inclusion can always be done via **https** and doesn't need to be adaptable to **http** or **https**; obviously it happens on server-side.

My specific problem was instead client-related, cause the resources (CSS, JS) from the included code were getting the scheme/protocol from the `<base href>` set in the container; so the cause was the latter one (that was always set to **http**), not because of the *ESI include*.